# University prevents student from exempting a class for medical reasons

Tags: medical, south-carolina

One of my friends has a seizure disorder and is majoring in engineering at a college in South Carolina. His seizures are really severe/dangerous and are caused by doing certain kinds of math. All of the math that he's had to do in college so far has been managable, but the math in two of his current classes is causing him to have seizures. Because of this, he ended up having to drop one of the classes and skip the assignments for one section of the other one for his safety. The problem is that both of these classes are required for his major and the department is refusing to offer a medical exemption (or alternate assignment that would be safer for him to perform) for either of these classes. He already tried getting the college's disability office to advocate in his favor, but the department still wouldn't budge.

So my question is: If my friend took legal action against the university for this, would he be able to get an exemption or alternate assignment for these classes? To me, this seems like discrimination against someone with a disability, but I don't know much about law and you guys are the experts on this sort of stuff!

Comment: Are seizures brought about by certain types of math problem a recognised disability? Does your friend have a clinical diagnosis?

Comment: Having a degree is a way of showing that someone has certain capabilities. Providing a degree to someone who has not those capabilities (even worse, who will be medically disabled for even performing those functions) seems like a no-no. Do you want an engineer who is not able to know if the bridge will collapse?

Comment: A lot of people are likely to be dismissive of this condition, so it's worth noting that [math-induced seizures](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7114810/) are a real thing.

Comment: @Weather Vane He has a clinical diagnoisis for his seizure disorder, although I don't think he has a diagnosis that explicitly states that they're caused by math because I don't think that's something you can even get a diagnosis for. But his doctor would definitely attest to the fact that math is a major trigger for him since he says he's had discussions with his doctor about this in the past, so maybe that would help his case a bit?

Comment: @bdb484 That's a really good point! A lot of people seem to doubt that this is true and that he's just using it as an excuse to get out of work (including the university itself, from what he's told me), but it's definitely a real thing.

Comment: Did your friend know about this condition before selecting engineering as a major?  Has he presented the University with a mitigation plan to prove his qualifications via alternate methods and complete the requirements necessary for his degree?

Comment: To expand on @SJuan76, engineering programs in the US are accredited by ABET which is recognized and satisfies requirements of state engineering licensure boards. Such regulation is a matter of public health and safety. The situation may be different in fields that do not have professional licensure, unlike engineering, geology/environmental science, medicine, and education.

Comment: Did the course description not have a Trigonometry Warning?

Comment: Is this math being done in a math class, or is it part of doing classes in the engineering curriculum? I've found little overlap between what I had to take for math in college and what I actually used in my career. However, if the student can't do what is needed to carry out engineering tasks, that is going to be a problem.

Comment: The math-induced-seizures link is from 1982 and starts "A patient with generalized convulsions noted that seizures were reliably precipitated by mental arithmetic."  A survey of 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The college probably is not allowed to discriminate w.r.t. disability (on the assumption that they receive federal money), so they are probably in the realm of [Section 504 and Iitle II](https://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/frontpage/faq/disability.html). [Here](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-34/subtitle-B/chapter-I/part-104) are the rules. On the face of it, the person might be handicapped. Start where is says

> (A) any physiological disorder or condition, cosmetic disfigurement,
> or anatomical loss affecting one or more of the following body
> systems: neurological; musculoskeletal; special sense organs;
> respiratory, including speech organs; cardiovascular; reproductive,
> digestive, genito-urinary; hemic and lymphatic; skin; and endocrine;
> or
>
> (B) any mental or psychological disorder, such as intellectual
> disability, organic brain syndrome, emotional or mental illness, and
> specific learning disabilities.

Then you look at the definitions of major life activities, impairment, and so on. The answers are not self-evident and often have to be litigated in novel cases. Being hard of hearing, color blind or hard of seeing does not count.

§104.12 says that the institution must make reasonable accommodations. That probably would not mean waiving the course requirement but could mean that they would have to find a different way to administer the exams. The institution could either argue that the student isn't handicapped (as is the current case for color blind students or those with age-related bad hearing and eyesight), or that no reasonable accommodation is possible. Either way, at the minimum, a formal complaint would be necessary.

Comment: And to address `To me, this seems like discrimination against someone with a disability` (from the OP's post). No, they are not discriminating against him. They expect him to do exactly the same than anyone else. It is the exact opposite of discrimination. The question is if they must (or even can) discriminate in his favor by providing accommodation.

Comment: @SJuan76 If a university fails a student who relies on a wheelchair for not attending classes reachable only by climbing stairs,the university is discriminating against him: they have not afforded him an equal opportunity to obtain the same benefits as students without a disability. That is how the word "discrimination" is used [in the regulation](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-34/subtitle-B/chapter-I/part-104/subpart-A/section-104.4). Providing accommodations for a student with a disability is not discrimination in that student's favor; it's what the law requires to prevent discrimination

Comment: It may, and this would require a detailed look at the specific facts, turn out to be that the accommodations required in this case would meet the high bar of [a fundamental alteration to an essential requirement](https://disabilitycenter.colostate.edu/policies-and-procedures/fundamental-alteration-and-accommodation-procedure/), such as if there's no viable way to teach the student the essential requirements of the program, but the university has to engage in the interactive process and consider other alternatives as part of reaching that conclusion instead of just issuing a blanket refusal.

Comment: That's not to say that an approach involving legal actions won't *eventually* work, but there's probably faster and less contentious ways to go about this.